# I-node storage in UNIX

Tags: unix, filesystems, inode

How many inodes are stored in every single disk block? Does every inode need to be stored in a separate block even if it does not completely fit in it?

Comment: The exact answer depends on the filesystem

Comment: Shouldn't this question be moved to another part of the SE network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of iNodes is a parameter that can be change while making the filesystem on a block device.

The parameter has it limits and it is diffrent on each Filesystem.

There is a default value for number of iNodes and it been calculated by the size of the Filesystem and the Filesystem type.

Every iNode will be stored in a diffrent block and even on number of diffrent blocks, even if it does not completely fit in.